# VBA is stopping before it is done

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a problem...

I have two datasets in the same workbook on different sheets.
The first column in both datasets are identifiers. In Sheet1 I have my dataset, and want to fill it with data from Sheet2 (which is also containing data (rows+Columns) that I do not want to use.

I have a VBA that is working, BUT, it stops before it is done.
E.g. I have 1598 Rows in Sheet2, but it stops working already after 567 rows..

```
Sub Test()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim Target As Worksheet

    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    j = 2    
    For Each c In Source.Range("A2", Source.Range("A" & Source.Cells(Source.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row))
        If c = Target.Cells(j, 1).Value Then
           Source.Range("D" & c.Row & ":AS" & c.Row).Copy Target.Cells(j, 26) 
           j = j + 1
        End If
    Next c
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Can someone help me and see if there is something obviously wrong with the code? I have tried it on smaller datasets, and then it works perfect.
If more information needed or you have some other tips, please ask/tell :D

Thanks!

Comment: Please specify what exactly *"it stops working already after 567 rows"* means? Do you get the message box in the end or not? Change it to `MsgBox "Done c=" & c & " j=" & j` and tell us the output of `c` and `j`. Also include the value of `Debug.Print Source.Cells(Source.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Thanks, I will have a try and see what it say. With "it stops working...", I only get result for the first 567 rows on Sheet1, even though I know there are more matches between the sheets.. :)

Comment: Note that this algorithm only compares source A2 with Target A2 and if this doesn't match then it will compare source A3 with target A2 and so on so your row countings diverge with every non-matching row. You might need to use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match` to get a proper maching instead.

Comment: Advice: `Dim j As Long` (not Integer) this will not fix your issue, but row variables should ALWAYS be `Long`

Comment: Side note: Do not use `Integer` types in VBA, they are just `Long` trunked and it goes From −32,768 to 32,767 so it could give you errors.

Comment: @PEH The MsgBox is giving me errors.. the `Debug.Print Source.Cells(Source.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` how would you print this? Do I need to add somewhere where it is printed or how would you recomend me to use it? Also, I do get results where A2 in Sheet1 matches A5 in Sheet2, but will have a look at the other function as well!

Comment: Sorry should be `MsgBox "Done c=" & c.row & " j=" & j` and `Debug.Print` output is in the immediate window in the VB Editor

Comment: @braX & Damian I have changed the variable to Long and will keep in mind to not use Integer, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### VBA Solution

Try the following, it usese the [WorksheetFunction.Match method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.match) to properly match the values of column A no matter which order they are.

It loops through all rows in Target, and tries to find a matching row in Source. If a match was found it copies it into the Target.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()
    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Set Source = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    Dim Target As Worksheet
    Set Target = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")


    Dim LastRowTarget As Long
    LastRowTarget = Target.Cells(Target.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim tRow As Long
    For tRow = 2 To LastRowTarget
        Dim sRowMatch As Double
        sRowMatch = 0 'reset match row
        On Error Resume Next 'ignore if next line throws error
        sRowMatch = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Target.Cells(tRow, 1).Value, Source.Columns("A"), 0)
        On Error GoTo 0 're-enable error reporting

        If sRowMatch <> 0 Then 'if matching does not find anything it will be 0 so <>0 means something was found to copy
            Source.Range("D" & sRowMatch & ":AS" & sRowMatch).Copy Target.Cells(tRow, 26)
        End If
    Next tRow

    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

#### Formula Solution

Note that there is no need for VBA and this could actually also solved with formulas only. Either the `VLOOKUP` formula or a combination of `INDEX` and `MATCH` formula.

So in Sheet1 cell Z2 write `=INDEX(Sheet2!D:D,MATCH($A2,Sheet2!$A:$A, 0))` and pull it down and right.

Comment: Thanks! This works perfect! Usually I would use one of those formulas as well, it is just a very formula heavy workbook that many people is working in, so I am trying to make buttons that is just to click to get the result we want in the most "simple" and non-heavy way for the file possible..